# Accessing LAN device using port triggering from a “mock internet” on the WAN port

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat, wan

Can I attach the WAN port of TP-Link Archer C59 WiFi router, a DHCP server (in my case Pi-Hole with dhcp enabled), a WAP (with an android tablet and iPad connected to it wirelessly) all to a switch and call it a “mock internet”?

Pi-Hole is there mainly to provide a “public address” and IPs to both tablets. The switch is providing a means to packet sniff. **I can’t actually test this with a real internet connection given limited access to resources.**

I am trying to simulate/test accessing a remote LAN device (10.113.x.x -static) from an app on the iPad and Android tablet via port triggering ports 443, 4503, and 4522 from the “mock internet”.

Up to this point, the expectation is that when I enter the public IP address 192.168.X.X in the app on the android tablet and/or iPad, I will connect to the LAN device for me to transfer files from LAN device to the app. This is not happening. Instead the app says it can’t find the device and that there is a connection error.

On the said switch I’m mirroring the port to which the WAP is hooked up to. I see the HTTPS “connection establishment requests” being sent from the tablets to the WAN port of the TP-Link, (in wireshark) but I see no reply. However before the HTTPS requests, the app pings the Public IP address which it then responds.

The TP-Link router, in the administrator section, in the traffic statistics section shows no WAN port traffic for the HTTPS connection requests.

My questions are as follows:

- In the web GUI of the TP-Link router, under the section “NAT”, which of the following best accomplish what I’m trying to do?

  - Port triggering- tried but didn’t work
  - Virtual server- tried but didn’t work
  - UnPnP
  - ALG
  - DMZ
- Is there a problem with having Pi-Hole dish out 192.168.x.x addresses to be used as a mock public IP address?
- Does a setup like this require I set up static routes in the TP-Link router?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I attach the WAN port of TP-Link Archer C59 WiFi router, a DHCP server (in my case Pi-Hole with dhcp enabled), a WAP (with an android tablet and iPad connected to it wirelessly) all to a switch and call it a “mock internet”?

The technology does not care about whether the WAN side is Internet or not. The Archer is just an IP router that sits between two IP subnets; the IP packets coming in from your Pi-Hole look the same as IP packets that would be coming in from your ISP or those going out to the LAN.

> I am trying to simulate/test accessing a remote LAN device (10.113.x.x -static) from an app on the iPad and Android tablet via port triggering ports 443, 4503, and 4522 from the “mock internet”.

"Port triggering" is the wrong feature to use. It is meant to automatically allow incoming connections **after a matching outgoing connection is detected.** For example, whenever a computer makes an *outgoing* connection to some remote server on port 6667 (IRC), the router automatically begins accepting incoming connections on port 113 (Ident) for a short duration.

You don't need this automation, and in your case there is no outgoing connection that would actually "trigger" the inbound rule to begin with. You want the inbound forwarding to be static and permanent. So what you should've configured instead is a **virtual server** (also known as "port forwarding" on many routers).

> In the web GUI of the TP-Link router, under the section “NAT”, which of the following best accomplish what I’m trying to do?

Other than the two already covered above:

- "UPnP" doesn't do anything on its own – it only lets a LAN computer *request* (using UPnP's IGD protocol) that the router add a 'virtual server' / 'port forwarding' entry for some port. The result of UPnP IGD requests is functionally identical to manually adding a 'virtual server' entry for that computer.
- "DMZ" just lets you designate a computer that will receive everything that is not matched by other rules. It is functionally the same as adding 'virtual server' entries for every possible port (and for all non-TCP/non-UDP protocols too).

  For example, if you add a 'virtual server' entry for TCP port 8080 → computer 1, then designate computer 2 as the 'DMZ' host, then all inbound connections on *all ports except TCP 8080* will go to computer 2. (Port 8080 will of course go to computer 1.)
- "ALG" (application-layer gateway) again deals with automatically adding rules, a bit like port triggering, but it works by inspecting the actual data sent using a few "difficult" protocols (e.g. SIP and FTP often need special handling). It does nothing for all other connections.

> Is there a problem with having Pi-Hole dish out 192.168.x.x addresses to be used as a mock public IP address?

If the addresses are on the *same network* as the TP-Link's LAN addresses (e.g. both using 192.168.1.0/24): Yes, very much so. (Some routers actually are capable of handling this situation, but that doesn't make it any less fundamentally ugly.)

If the addresses are on a different network than TP-Link's LAN: No, it's not a problem technically, unless it happens to trigger some smart "chained router detection" feature in the Archer.

If in doubt, you can try changing the Pi-Hole to use e.g. a subnet from the 100.64.0.0/10 range (e.g. 100.64.0.0/24 or 100.127.42.0/24) – this is also private-use but it's meant to be specifically used on the ISP's side.

(When the system is fully isolated from the Internet, you can temporarily configure the Pi-Hole to use *any* IP address range, even those considered 'public' and belonging to real operators.)

> Does a setup like this require I set up static routes in the TP-Link router?

No. It already has 'local subnet' routes for the two networks it's a direct member of.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I’ll try the virtual server and the other suggestions and get back to you, again, much appreciated.

Comment: the virtual server settings along with addressing  one or two other gaps in my setup led to a successful test environment. Thanks again for your detailed answer!